# Small Example for pyserial using Threading

Tags: python, multithreading, pyserial

Can anyone please give me a small and simple example on how to use threading with pyserial communication.
I am googling for over three days and I am still illeterate and I dont even have a working piece of code which integrate both of them

Basically I am aiming to use threading in this scenario:

Have a serial communication continuously go on in the back ground to attain certain value (say A) from an MCU.

Stop attaining value A - then attain value B...and start continuously attaining value A again.

You can find some basic code here.

```
import threading
import time
import sys
import serial
import os
import time

def Task1(ser):

    while 1:

        print "Inside Thread 1"
        ser.write('\x5A\x03\x02\x02\x02\x09') # Byte ArrayTo Control a MicroProcessing Unit
        b = ser.read(7)
        print b.encode('hex')
        print "Thread 1 still going on"
        time.sleep(1)


def Task2(ser):

    print "Inside Thread 2"
    print "I stopped Task 1 to start and execute Thread 2"
    ser.write('x5A\x03\x02\x08\x02\x0F')
    c = ser.read(7)
    print c.encode('hex')
    print "Thread 2 complete"


def Main():
    ser = serial.Serial(3, 11520)
    t1 = threading.Thread(target = Task1, args=[ser])
    t2 = threading.Thread(target = Task2, args=[ser])
    print "Starting Thread 1"
    t1.start()
    print "Starting Thread 2"
    t2.start()

    print "=== exiting ==="

    ser.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    Main()
```

Comment: Please clean up your indentation since it actually matters in python...

Comment: So for starters your comment in thread2 says "I stopped Task 1", but well you didn't.  Also, since you don't `join` with your threads, you immediately close the serial port `ser.close()`, most likely before your threads even start.

Comment: @Andy Edited  Could you please provide me a code snippet. I understand what you said, but I dont know how to stop a thread. I have an another one with lock - but it also fails. I did not use t1.join() because I should be able to exit the main program when t1 is still in use.

Comment: I'd suggest your look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects very carefully.  Note thread.start() doesn't synchronously start - it returns immediately and the thread is only scheduled to start later.

Comment: How would I terminate a thread?

Comment: The thread needs to terminate itself by exiting the Task1 or Task2 functions.  For example only loop a set number of times in Task 1 then join on it in the main thread.  Task2 already exits on its own.  Neither matter though because you aren't joining on them in main, hence your program is effectively doing the following: start->open serial port->close serial port->exit before any threads actually kick off.

Comment: That is the problem Andy - I cant have a loop to set number of times. I want to have it continuously as long as the program is running - where I am doing other stuff like Task2. If I use t1.join() I cannot close the program until it is done. I should be able to stop the program even t1 is working

Comment: Ok.  You need to first ask yourself - what is the condition for program termination?

Comment: This is just a small code snippet of a major GUI I am writing. There is a button on the GUI - EXIT- which when clicked closes my GUI and should also stop this task1. The task 1 starts when I open the GUI and click START COMMUNICATION and should stops when I close the GUI - by clicking EXIT BUTTON. In the meantime. I have other functions - where I want to stop task 1  -- to do task 2, task 3 etc. and restart task 1 again

Comment: Doing serial communications in a Thread is A Good Thing, but using multiple threads could be a problem (if serial can't write while a read is pending).  I typically send and receive to a given port using a single thread/class and the rest of the program goes through that class.  There is always a read pending, with a timeout, and after each read (or timeout) it checks the "outgoing" queue to see if there is a send required, and if there is, sends it, then goes back to reading.  So you clearly want a short timeout on the read for response considerations.

Answer (score 0):

There's no factual basis for the claim by `Task2`:

```
print "I stopped Task 1 to start and execute Thread 2"
```

Your implementation starts one thread then immediately starts the other *without* stopping the first.  This means that the `ser.read` and `ser.write` commands could interfere with each other.

The simplest thing you could do to address this is to introduce variables that allow communication:

```
import sys
import os
import time
import threading

thread_flag = None


def Report(s):
    print s
    sys.stdout.flush() # helps to ensure messages from different threads appear in the right order

def Stop():
    global thread_flag
    thread_flag = 'stop'

def Task1(ser):

    Report("Inside Thread 1")
    global thread_flag
    thread_flag = 'go'

    while True:

        Report("Thread 1 waiting for permission to read")
        while thread_flag != 'go': time.sleep( 0.001 )

        while thread_flag == 'go':
            Report("Thread 1 is reading")
            #ser.write('\x5A\x03\x02\x02\x02\x09') # Byte ArrayTo Control a MicroProcessing Unit
            #b = ser.read(7)
            #Report(b.encode('hex'))
            time.sleep(1)

        if thread_flag == 'stop': break
        else: thread_flag = 'paused'   # signals that the inner loop is done

    Report("Thread 1 complete")


def Task2(ser):

    Report("Inside Thread 2")

    global thread_flag
    thread_flag = 'pause' # signals Task1 to pause
    while thread_flag != 'paused': time.sleep(0.001) # waits for Task1 inner loop to exit
    Report("I stopped Task 1 to start and execute Thread 2")

    #ser.write('x5A\x03\x02\x08\x02\x0F')
    #c = ser.read(7)
    #Report(c.encode('hex'))

    thread_flag = 'go' # signals Thread 1 to resume
    Report("Thread 2 complete")


def Main():
    ser = None # serial.Serial(3, 11520)
    t1 = threading.Thread(target = Task1, args=[ser])
    t2 = threading.Thread(target = Task2, args=[ser])
    Report("Starting Thread 1")
    t1.start()

    time.sleep(3)
    Report("Starting Thread 2")
    t2.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    Main()
```

That approach uses a global variable, which is often frowned upon. You could instead make `Task1` and `Task2` methods of an object `self` that carries both `self.ser` and `self.thread_flag` as attributes.

For any inter-thread communication more complex than this, you need to investigate locks, mutexes and semaphores (e.g. `threading.Lock`)

Comment: How would I stop a thread? Could you please provide me a code snippet that works.

Comment: I am investigating locks since yesterday - no luck. Your code gave me an error ser -- is not open. So I added t2.join() but still no luck. I am unable to close the main thread. When thread 1 - t1 is running.  I also set t1.setDaemon(True) - the code is an infiinte loop now and nothing is being printed.

Comment: `ser is not open` is not a problem originating from my snippet. That and the threading are separate issues. Use your existing `Main` and make sure `ser` is open going in.

Comment: Yeah I fixed that and I just have a terminal where it is not exiting the main thread.
Starting Thread 1 --- starting thread 2 --- inside thread 1 -- -then exiting---- Inside thread 2
Thats it,  it is like that for over a 1 minute

Comment: try commenting out all the `ser.`-specific lines. Get the threading communication to work first (I have commented them out in my last edit, which now addresses your original problem of wanting to pause *and resume* thread 1)